# How to test VXML code (JUnit ) using java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, junit, vxml

I have a requirement wherein I have to test VXML code using java or be it any interface like JMeter or SOAPUI.
The code contains servlets where the request comes in first, data is processed and validated, and then it is forwarded to jsp. Over there vxml is generated and response in pushed into it. 
Generation of vxml in jsp is during runtime.

I tried using mockito (for mocking few classes response )and JUnit to test each API(servlet) but there are dependencies on the DB. The API is unable to proceed further and it fails(tried this locally).
The requirement in testing two similar vxml files that is generated as API response in two different environments and validating whether these two vxml files are equal or not.
Also tried comparing xmls using java but that was not sufficient and validation was incomplete.
I am looking out for open source approach rather than going for paid tools like cyara etc..
Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated.!!
Thanks.

Comment: The dependency of the DB can be mocked. Why was this not enough -  'tried comparing xmls using java but that wasn not sufficient'?

Comment: If you cannot decouple the database (so you can use one you control for testing) it is diligent to do so now.